# Not able to construct and run a ssh command

Tags: python, ssh

I am trying to construct and run an ssh command as "ssh -p 29418 servacc@company.com gerrit review --option 1 change,patchnum" based on the change
and patchnum given,can anyone provide guidane on how to do it?

```
change = '700293'
patchnum = '1'


def lock (change,patchnum):
    #Construct ssh command

    #ssh -p 29418 servacc@company.com gerrit review --option 1 change,patchnum



lock(change,patchnum)
```

Comment: Also consider using Fabric, which streamlines running commands over  SSH in Python: http://fabric.readthedocs.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a system call - use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module:

```
from subprocess import call

def lock(change,patchnum):
    #Construct ssh command
    #ssh -p 29418 servacc@company.com gerrit review --option 1 change,patchnum
    call(["ssh -p 29418 servacc@company.com gerrit review --option 1 %d,%d" %(change,patchnum)],shell=True) 


change = 700293
patchnum = 1 
lock(change,patchnum)
```

Comment: getting an errror TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str

Comment: how to convert string to digit?

Comment: First, ["how to convert string to digit"](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=how+to+convert+string+to+digit&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).  I don't think that's what you want to do - instead, just remove the quotes from the numbers.  `change=700293` rather than `change='700293'`